# The code change is not reflecting in the Jar

Tags: maven, jar, build

I've applied a git patch on my local repository to get some changes from my fellow-developer. The patch was successfully applied, and I see the changes to the java files.
I did a 'mvn clean install' on the project, it did build successfully but the changes is not visible to another java class which depends on the new changes(this jar).
When I extracted the jar and decompiled the class file I found the changes are not part of the compiled class. Could not understand this behaviour.

in simple words .. the java files has got the new changes but the generated JAR does not have the changes.

Need some advice if someone has faced this issue.

Comment: Has this jar also being deployed to repository manager ? Apart from that if it is a SNAPSHOT does the other one made an `mvn -U clean package` to get the new SNASPHOT ?

Comment: deploying to the repository manager comes next, but the created jar does not has the code changes,

Comment: I would need a bit more information to help. What maven command are you running. Also can we see your pom.xml?

Comment: thanks, found the issue, it was not Maven's, my local git repo had an issue !!

Answer (score 1):

Thankyou... Found the issue, the local git repo had an issue, there were hidden files in the same repo that was causing this issue, I deleted my local repo and re-cloned it, its working now.